# Sum of Specific String Elements in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

So, I have a data frame in pandas which contains a column called "Tracking". Now the column contains different values like "Received", "In Progress", "Delayed due to something" etc. I am wondering is there a possibility that i can get the sum of each of these status from this column. so for example

Input

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Tracking': ['Received', 'Received', 'In Progress', 'Delayed due to something'], 'col2':...})
```

Output:

```
Received : 2
In Progress: 1
Delayed due to something :1
```

I know this question might have been asked previously if there is a answer please provide a link if not any help is appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Tracking': ['Received', 'Received', 'In Progress', 'Delayed due to something','In Progress','In Progress']})

print(df.Tracking.value_counts())
```

```
In Progress                 3
Received                    2
Delayed due to something    1
Name: Tracking, dtype: int64
```